# Can't write an integer into a binary file C++

Tags: c++, file-io, binary

This is basically the part of the code that i used to store the entire file, and works well ... but when i tryed to store a integer bigger than 120 or something like that the program writes seems like a bunch of trash and not the integer that i want. Any tips ? I am an college student and dont have a clue whats happening.

```
    int* temp

    temp = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));

    *temp = atoi( it->valor[i].c_str() );

    //Writes the integer in 4 bytes
    fwrite(temp, sizeof (int), 1, arq);

    if( ferror(arq) ){
      printf("\n\n Error \n\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    free(temp);
```

I've already checked the `atoi` part and it really returns the number that I want to write.

Comment: How do you verify that not the correct number was written?

Comment: You'll need to post a complete (and hopefully minimal) example if you want to get help that's not just wild guesses. The code you showed so far looks ok. Are you sure `it->valor[i]` is always a valid string?

Comment: No reason to `malloc` that, just create an `int temp`, and pass the address of it to `fwrite`, like `fwrite(&temp, sizeof(temp), 1, arq);`

Comment: This is appallingly bad C++. Please don’t mix C and C++.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - it's also bad C.

Answer (score 2):

I changed and added some code and it works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int* temp;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("file.bin" , "rb+"); // Opening the file using rb+ for writing
                                      // and reading binary data
    temp = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));

    *temp = atoi( "1013" );           // replace "1013" with your string

    //Writes the integer in 4 bytes
    fwrite(temp, sizeof (int), 1, file);

    if( ferror(file) ){
      printf("\n\n Error \n\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    free(temp);
}
```

Make sure you are opening the file with the correct parameters, and that the string you give to atoi(str) is correct.

I checked the binary file using hex editor, after inputting the number 1013.

Comment: Please do not advocate bad C++ code in an answer (see my answer for reasons).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Roy ! That is the strange part, my program is exactly like yours and when i open the file with my hex editor after write 1001 for example he shows this: hex 4D 00 00 00 decimal 077 000 000 000 octal 115 000 000 000 binary 01001101 00000000 00000000 00000000. Im using Linux Ubuntu x64 and g++

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Yea didn't even notice it, thanks for the comment. I usually write in c++ but the fact that his original code contained C syntax confused me, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = atoi("123");
std::ofstream file("filename", std::ios::bin);
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i), sizeof(i));
```

- Do not use pointers here.
- **Never** use `malloc` / `free` in C++.
- Use C++ file streams, not C streams.